# Fill form with all unique data by 50 users in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I want to test one form of Add student which contains lots of fields , I want that 50 users comes to that form , enter unique data and submit it. So when I check in my site , there should be new 50 students added.

I have set all test plan in jmeter but how can I set/get unique field values for all 50 users in Jmeter? I have worked with all type of scenarios in jmeter but this one is new for me so need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following [JMeter Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

- [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) - returns number of current thread (virtual user). If you use something like `User${__threadNum}` it will be `User1` for first thread, `User2` for second thread, etc.
- [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) - returns random string of specified length from characters provided. For instance `${__RandomString(,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789,10)}` will return random alpha-numeric string of 10 characters
- [__UUID()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID) - returns unique [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) structure, something like `eed5f026-a4a7-4481-9c3e-ce1a0129c25d`
- [__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) - returns next string from the specified file each time being called. If file end is reached it starts over from the beginning.

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series for more detailed information on above and other functions.

Comment: will these functions enough to complete my test given test case or I will also have to use CSV?

Comment: I would prefer to avoid having extra data sources where possible, if you don't have a pre-defined data set - it's better go for random stuff.

Answer (score 1):

To test your application with multiple sets of data, you need to add CSV Dataset Config element to your test plan and add all the test to the CSV file and place it under bin folder.

Refer [this](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) link for more details.

Comment: Yes I can use CSV , but how can I set like diff. csv for diff. threads.

Comment: You need to add respective CSV to the respective thread group. It will not overlap during execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSV file as an input, one row for one user, each with unique data defined upfront.

If you want, you can also generate random data on the fly, but in most scenarios CSV file is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes I can use CSV , but how can I set like diff. csv for diff. threads

Answer (score 0):

1. You can give user's number with some string for your values using `${__threadNum}` method, If you want even iteration you can use `${__BeanShell(vars.getIteration(),)}` method with the combination of user and iteration.
2. You can use `_UUID()` method for creating random string.
3. The greatest way is to get the current time and date and put it as value, that will be unique always. `${__time(hh:mm a,)}` use it in any format.

Thank you.